# C++ - Declare pointer to function returning any type and getting any number of parameters

Tags: c++, function-pointers, parameter-pack

I was wondering if writing anything resembling this declaration (making use of the parameter pack) is possible.

```
decltype(auto) (*funcPtr)(...);
```

If possible, I would also like to know about alternative ways to declare such a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a *statically typed* language. All function argument types and return types *must* be known at compile time. You cannot declare a function that returns arbitrary types (well, I guess you *could* return `std::any`, but I can't think of a case where you'd want to).

You *can* use templates, however, to create function templates where the compiler will stamp out multiple versions of a function for you, so you don't have to write them all yourself.

Remember that `auto` and `decltype(auto)` is *not* magic. They are just syntactic sugar for what you'd otherwise write yourself if they didn't exist. They do *not* enable any new features that weren't already in the language. They just make such features easier to use.

Comment: But I can declare a function that takes an arbitrary number of parameters using variadic templates. How does that concept fit with your answer?

Comment: @daniglezad that would be a *template* function.

Comment: Ok, so I can not achieve my purpose using templated functions with variadic templates either because it is not possible to have a pointer to a templated function. Is this correct?

Comment: @daniglezad correct. Although, you can have a template variable that points to the respective instance of a function template, each having a Return type specified by a template argument.

Comment: @eerorika okay thanks! could you translate that into an answer? Maybe it is more understandable with an example.

Comment: @daniglezad I wrote an example.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no type such as pointer to function "that returns anything". There are only pointers to a function that returns some type or `void`. `auto` merely deduces the type from an initialiser, and there is nothing to deduce the type from in your example.

You can however have a function template where the instance of the template is a function that returns a type specified by a template argument:

```
// function template
template<class T>
T foo() {
    return {};
}
```

Likewise, you can have a variable template that is a pointer to function whose return type is specified by a template variable:

```
// variable template
template<class T>
T (*funcPtr)() = foo;

// example usage
int main() {
    return funcPtr<int>();
}
```